# Integrating backend code (Java, Python) with HTML

Tags: java, python, html, encryption, web

I'm experienced with back-end code with languages such as Java and Python but for an upcoming project, I need to integrate this code to a website.

The backend code will be a bunch of methods and classes that will be able to encrypt text messages with encryption such as AES. For this project, this system must be implemented on the web.

I've been reading around and asked some people and it seems there are ways to use this Python or Java code on a webpage without having to rewrite it in something like PHP. I've seen some things like Django but I'm not sure what would be the best option for this project.

The webpage will simply do the following:

1. User selects an encryption type, gives key, and their message.
2. This message is then encrypted using their choice of key and encryption.

Suppose the encryption methods are already ready, how would I be able to connect the input on the webpage (text field, drop down menu, and button click) to my program and call the appropriate functions and display the returned values?

I'm sure this is possible but I'm not sure which option would be best for this task.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure that there are three million and one web frameworks for Python and I know there are at least that many for Java. This question is too vague for anyone to be able to provide a more cogent answer than "You need to do some reading". Something [like this](http://www.journaldev.com/1854/java-web-application-tutorial-for-beginners) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remember that before reaching your server, the data has to pass from the user's browser to your server (i.e. over the Internet). If you want the data the user is sending to be encrypted on the way to your server then you need to set up a certificate and use HTTPS. This is irrespective of whether you are going to use Java, Python, PHP or anything else on the server side.

For what you need then, if you are using Java, what you would do is have a servlet container (such as Apache Tomcat) and develop a Servlet (which is a normal class that extends [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)) and in its `doPost()` method, which receives the data from the user, calls your respective methods, and outputs the message (ideally in HTML format, enclosed in `<html>`, `<body>`, `<p>` tags)

You would also need to create a small HTML form (could be a simple HTML file if there is nothing dynamic in it and just has a form with a dropdown of the encryption choices and a text area where he puts the data). The action of the form would direct to the servlet above, that calls the encryption methods.

Both the servlet and the HTML file need to be bundled in a webapp war file, which is then deployed in Tomcat.

There are obviously much more details to this, but hopefully you have enough keywords to get you started with building a 'hello world' web application with a simple servlet.

I suppose there are similar things for Python too, make friends with Google!

Comment: The idea was to encrypt in the page, not at the server according to the question. So the encryption would need to be performed e.g. in a script within the page.

Comment: @owlstead How did you infer that? He just said he wanted a web page that shows a dropdown to choose the encryption and a method to put the key and message. He also indicated he wanted to use Java or Python.

Comment: Hmm, re-reading the question I'm not sure either. Just a second. OK, changed it to an upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll do some more reading and see what I can come up with. This is just what I needed, some guidance to point me to where I should begin reading. :)